# Maximum limit of IO_TCPDF generation

Tags: symfony, io, tcpdf

I'm trying to export pdf using IO TCPDF (I'm using Symfony 2) but when the amount of data I try to export is over 650 rows, I get this error message:

```
"Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/html/AiresProxyAudit/vendor/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 23099"
```

I change the values of those variables `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time` in order to increase the amount of data I can export, but each time it happens the same. What am I doing wrong? this is my code.
thanks, and hope you guys can help me on this.

public function export_urlAction($name) {
        $usuario = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUserName();

```
    $dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager')
            ->getRepository('ReportesBundle:RporURL')
            ->url($this->get_id($usuario,$name));

    $totalurls = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager')
            ->getRepository('ReportesBundle:RTotales')
            ->total($this->get_id($usuario,$name), "url");

    $reportes = array();
    $totales = array();

    foreach ($dm as $value) {


        $reportes[] = $value;
    }

    foreach ($totalurls as $value) {
        $totales[] = $value;
    }

    $html = $this->renderView('ReportesBundle:PDF:pdfurl.pdf.twig', array('reporte' => $reportes, 'totales' => $totales));

    //io_tcpdf will returns Response object
    return $this->get('io_tcpdf')->quick_pdf($html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for it, I divided pdf generation into 3 twig templates:
$arrayHtmll = array();
        $html = $this->renderView('ReportesBundle:PDF:pdfurl.pdf.twig', array('reporte' => $totalRUrl[0], 'totales' => $totales));
        $arrayHtmll[] = $html;
        for ($index = 1; $index < count($totalRUrl)-1; $index++) {
            $html = $this->renderView('ReportesBundle:PDF:pdfurlmedio.pdf.twig', array('reporte' => $totalRUrl[$index], 'totales' => $totales));  //agregue el twig del medio
            $arrayHtmll[] = $html;
        }
        $html = $this->renderView('ReportesBundle:PDF:pdfurlfinal.pdf.twig', array('reporte' => $totalRUrl[count($totalRUrl)-1], 'totales' => $totales));
        $arrayHtmll[] = $html;

foreach ($arrayHtmll as $value){
            $fff->writeHTML($value, false, false, true, false, '');

I probe it with mongo database with 26020 documents and I haven't issues to generate it. I changed the value of the variable memory_limit of php file to 256.